# onInvalidSubmit dose not work in vee-validate version (^4.5.2)

Tags: vue.js, validation, vuejs3, vee-validate

I am trying to capture errors in forms and have to display them in modal. But vee-validate onInvaidSubmit seems not working. See code below.

PS: I copied this example from https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/guide/components/handling-forms

Vue Version : 3, vee-validate: 4.5.11

```
<template>
  <Form v-slot="{ validate }" :validation-schema="schema">
    <Field name="email" type="email" />
    <ErrorMessage name="email" />
    <Field name="password" type="password" />
    <ErrorMessage name="password" />
    <button @click="validate">Submit</button>
  </Form>
</template>
<script>
import { Form, Field, ErrorMessage } from 'vee-validate'
import * as yup from 'yup'
export default {
  components: {
    Form,
    Field,
    ErrorMessage,
  },
  data() {
    const schema = yup.object({
      email: yup.string().required().email(),
      password: yup.string().required().min(8),
    })
    return {
      schema,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmit(values) {
      // Submit values to API...
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2))
    },
    onInvalidSubmit({ values, errors, results }) {
      console.log(values) // current form values
      console.log(errors) // a map of field names and their first error message
      console.log(results) // a detailed map of field names and their validation results
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following by adding it to the Form element.  see below

```
<Form v-slot="{ validate }" :validation-schema="schema" @invalid-submit="onInvalidSubmit">
  <Field name="email" type="email" />
  <ErrorMessage name="email" />
  <Field name="password" type="password" />
  <ErrorMessage name="password" />
  <button @click="validate">Submit</button>
</Form>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).